# Query in Rename of a primary key in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

If I rename a column which is a primary key in that table, so will it still be the primary key after renaming. And if I also had referenced that column to some other column of other table, so will it be referenced or I have to reference it again?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen if you rename the primary key column - not regarding constraints, that is.

Master and detail tables:

```
SQL> create table master (id_master number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table detail (id_detail  number primary key,
  2                       id_det_mas number references master (id_master));

Table created.
```

Let's rename master's primary key column:

```
SQL> alter table master rename column id_master to changed_name;

Table altered.
```

How do constraints look like?

```
SQL> select constraint_name, r_constraint_name
  2  from user_constraints C
  3  where table_name = 'DETAIL'
  4    and constraint_type = 'R';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS_C007215                    SYS_C007213

SQL> select *
  2  from user_cons_Columns
  3  where constraint_name in ('SYS_C007215', 'SYS_C007213');

OWNER  CONSTRAINT_NAME TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME       POSITION
------ --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
SCOTT  SYS_C007213     MASTER          CHANGED_NAME             1
SCOTT  SYS_C007215     DETAIL          ID_DET_MAS               1

SQL>
```

As you can see, constraint `SYS_C007213` (on `MASTER`) contains `CHANGED_NAME` column.

Does the referential constraint work properly?

```
SQL> insert into master values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into detail values (100, 200);
insert into detail values (100, 200)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C007215) violated - parent key not
found


SQL>
```

Yes, it does.

---

Should you rename primary key column(s)? Most probably not. In early stage of application development, *maybe* (but the fact that you CAN do it doesn't mean that you SHOULD do it). However, once you created front-end application and used that column *everywhere*, it'll become a nightmare to fix it and make it work properly. I wouldn't do it, if I were you.